# polyline decoder giving StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, json, polyline

I've an app that parses a json response after being given 2 postcodes in the url request to google maps. I've got the overviewpolyline node from the response and cast that to a string. i presume the overviewpolyline node is the entire route as a polyline.

below is some code that i've found that when is passed a polyline as a string, it converts that string to a list of GeoPoints. i've checked to see if the polyline string is not empty and for say 2 postcodes there were 700+ characters in the string. so no problems there.

I've marked where the exception occurs in the code source below. Any ideas why there is an index error. the looping is controlled with a 'while' statement and only iterates when less than the length of the polyline.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List decodePolyLine(final String poly) {



         int len = poly.length();
         Log.e(TAG, "poly string length = "+poly.length());
         int index = 0;
         List decoded = new ArrayList();
         int lat = 0;
         int lng = 0;


         while (index < len) {

         int b;
         int shift = 0;
         int result = 0;

         do {

         b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;

         result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;

         shift += 5;



    } while (b >= 0x20);



         int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
         lat += dlat;
         shift = 0;
         result = 0;

         do {

         b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;     <--------****error here****
         result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
         shift += 5;

         } while (b >= 0x20);



         int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
         lng += dlng;

         decoded.add(new GeoPoint(

                 (int)(lat*1e6) , (int)(lon * 1e6)));

         }

         return decoded;

         }//end of decodePolyLine
```

Comment: i've just noticed overviewpolyline has a nested object "points". gonna look at that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. the problem wasn't to do with the above code, rather how i was parsing the json response. i needed to get the points object within the overviewpolyline object. eg

```
JSONObject results = null;

        try {

            results = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);


            routes = results.getJSONArray("routes");

            anonObject = routes.getJSONObject(0);
            bounds = anonObject.getJSONObject("bounds");
            overViewPolyline = anonObject.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            polyPoints = overViewPolyline.getString("points");
            Log.e(TAG,"overview_polyline  = " + overViewPolyline);
            Log.e(TAG,"points  = " + polyPoints);


            northeast = bounds.getJSONObject("northeast");


            lat =  (Double) northeast.get("lat");


            lon = (Double) northeast.get("lng");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some encoded "overview_polyline" that we get from that directions response is encoded, has double encoded backslashes. To work in the request for a static map, the \ needs to be translated to \